# Displaying statement result doesn't work after checking results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've wrote a code to select data from my database, and I test if the statement returns something or no with `fetchColumn()` and I display the results if it's not null using a loop with `fetch()`. But event when the results exist it soesn't show me anything.. Here's my code :

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT NOM_Etudiant, PRENOM_Etudiant FROM Etudiant WHERE CNE_Etudiant = :cnev AND PASS_Etudiant = :passv');
$req->execute(array('cnev' => $cne, 'passv' => $pass));

$count = $req->fetchColumn();
if(!$count) {
    header('Location: authentification_etud.php?status=invalid');
}
else {
    // Doesn't work
    while ($donnees = $req->fetch())
    {
        echo '<strong>Bienvenue </strong>' . $donnees['NOM_Etudiant'] . ' ' . $donnees['PRENOM_Etudiant'] . ' ! ' ;
    }
}
```

Do you know why it doesn't work ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `rowCount()` method to determine the number of rows not `fetchColumn()`.  `fetchColumn()` will actually advance the pointer in the result set to where you will no longer have access to the first row of data.

Notice the big red warning on this page http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php

Comment: thank you. But it said in the doc that : PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement. what about the select ?

Comment: @Mehdi The message there in the documentation is a warning that rowCount() may not work for compatibility reasons with all DB's that PDO can be used with.  For MySQL it works. Would be nice if the documentation made that clear since MySQL is the largest use case.

Comment: I changed the line of fetchRow() with : `$count = $req->rowColumn();` and it gives me the error : _Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::rowColumn()_ and i'm using MySQL. Any idea ?

Comment: Not `rowColumn()` but `rowCount()`

Comment: Hahahahahaha thank you :D I don't know why did I write `rowColumn()` XD

Answer (score 0):

`fetchColumn` returns one value of the first column **and** moves the result pointer to the next dataset. So, when calling `fetch()`, you don't get the first, but the **second** dataset (or nothing, if there is only one row).

Instead of using `fetchColumn()` you could just use `rowCount()` to check if there are results.

Comment: PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. and it's said that for select : use PDOStatement::fetchColumn()

Comment: @Mehdi: You are probably referring to [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.rowcount.php). However, there it says to use `fetchColumn()` with a **second, seperate `COUNT(*)` query**. If you use `fetchColumn()` on your primary query, you just get the first column of the first result row. For MySQL, using `rowCount()` works absolutely fine.